# Make two TEdits exclusive

Tags: delphi, text, edit

I have two TEdit boxes that I am using to specify file paths, one is for UNC paths, the other is for a local path. However, I would like it so if the user can only enter text in one box. If they enter text in one box, it should clear the other one. How should I go about doing this? Also, not sure if I should use an OnEnter, OnChange, or some other method.

Comment: `OnExit` is the event you should look into, I think.

Comment: Probably 'OnChange' would work. I would simply provide two extra radio buttons and force the user select one..

Comment: I'm with Sertac. one TEdit, two radio buttons. btw, that is the difference between UNC and local path?

Comment: Technically they are the same, but our users tend to think of a UNC as shared eg: \\somecomputer\folder and a local path as C:\somefolder

Comment: See [Principles_of_user_interface_design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_user_interface_design). The only sensible thing is follow Sertac's approach.

Comment: I agree with Sertac: sudden deletion of user input is puzzling at best and will lead to user frustration.

Comment: Why bother differentiating?  Also, how does `\\?\C:\somefolder` get detected?

Comment: With the radio button approach, you could disable (gray out) the other box rather than clear it. This makes it easy for the user to switch back and forth without having to retype information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it pretty simply. Create one OnChange handler, and assign it to both TEdits using the Object Inspector's Events tab. Then you can use something like the following:

```
procedure TForm1.EditChanged(Sender: TObject); //Sender is the edit being changed
begin
  if Sender = UNCEdit then  // If it's is the UNCEdit being changed
  begin
    LocalPathEdit.OnChange := nil;            // Prevent recursive calling!
    LocalPathEdit.Text := '';                 // Clear the text
    LocalPathEdit.OnChange := EditChanged;    // Restore the event handler
  end;
  else
  begin
    UNCEdit.OnChange := nil;
    UNCEdit.Text := '';
    UNCEdit.OnChange := EditChanged;
  end;
end;
```

This can be streamlined slightly, but it's not quite as readable to others. It can also be protected with a try..finally, although for simply clearing an edit's text content it's not really needed.

```
procedure TForm1.EditChanged(Sender: TObject);
var
  TmpEdit: TEdit;
begin
  if Sender = UNCEdit then
    TmpEdit := LocalPathEdit
  else
    TmpEdit := UNCEdit;
  TmpEdit.OnChange := nil;
  try
    TmpEdit.Text := '';
  finally
    TmpEdit.OnChange := EditChanged;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Here with D7, setting the `Text` property does noet trigger an `OnChange` event, so you could ommit the recursion prevention. `Edit.Clear` dóes trigger OnChange though!

Comment: If I'm remembering correctly, there were a couple of versions of Delphi that did call it (I could be wrong, though). It doesn't hurt anything to make sure that it doesn't recurse just in case, though. :) There's no overhead to clearing/restoring the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the two edit boxes, this is how I would do it.

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (Edit1.text <> '') then
    Edit2.text:= '';
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit2Exit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (Edit2.text <> '') then
    Edit1.text:= '';
end;
```

You want the value check so that you don't accidentally wipe the value when your users tab through the fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could hook both edit boxes to the following KeyPress event

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  If Sender = Edit1 then
    Edit2.clear
  else
  if Sender = Edit2 then
    Edit1.clear;
end;
```

Comment: You don't need the typecast; the equality of `Sender = Edit1` works fine without it, as you're comparing the addresses of two TObject pointers.